# SQL query for the following Schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

DB Schema

**students table**

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ student_id ║ first_name  ║ last_name    ║ advisor_id  ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║          1 ║ Tanisha     ║ Blake        ║ 2           ║
║          2 ║ Jess        ║ Goldsmith    ║ NULL        ║
║          3 ║ Tracy       ║ Wu           ║ 3           ║
║          4 ║ Alvin       ║ Grand        ║ 1           ║
║          5 ║ Felix       ║ Zimmermann   ║ 2           ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Advisors table**

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ advisor_id ║ first_name ║ last_name ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║          1 ║ James      ║ Francis   ║
║          2 ║ Amy        ║ Cheng     ║
║          3 ║ Lamar      ║ Alexander ║
║          4 ║ Anita      ║ Woods     ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

1. Get all students First name,Last name **and** advisors First and Last name excluding advisors with no students assigned

Comment: Add the expected result(s) as well. Formatted text please. And show us your query attempts. (If we do your homework for you, you wont learn much.)

Comment: To answer your question - no the questions are not the same.

Comment: Why is this question changed instead of changing this one you should have created a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same as the first will exclude students and the second won't.

Comment: can you tell me what would be the query for the second question pls

Comment: As BlindSniper proposed smth like: `SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, a.first_name, a.last_name FROM students s LEFT OUTER JOIN advisors ON s.advisor_id = a.advisor_id;`

Answer (score -1):

Yes both question are same in case u use inner join as it will not consider recordsets from each table, which do not have corresponding results in other table. But in case you use outer joins then you may have to put condition of weeding out records with null value in other table.

Foe example consider this query

```
Select * from students s left outer join advisers a on ( s.avisor_id = a.adviser_id)
```

This query will not only print those students with adviser but will also give students without adviser . SO simply putting a check for check Adviser_id is null will weed out not required record sets